# Select hr.employee by user_id in odoo 7

Tags: python

I want to select **hr.employee** automatically by **user_id** in `def read`

the field is :

```
'tested_by':fields.many2one("hr.employee",string="Tested by"),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `_defaults`:

```
def _get_employee(self, cr, uid, context=None):
    res = self.pool.get('hr.employee').search(cr, uid, [('user_id', '=', uid)], context=c)
    return res and res[0] or False

_columns = {
    'tested_by':fields.many2one("hr.employee",string="Tested by"),
}

_defaults = {
    'tested_by': _get_employee,
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it's helpful